# ReactiveCocoa MVVM with UITableView

Tags: objective-c, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I'm using ReactiveCocoa and am trying to apply MVVM. I have a fairly typical UITableView scenario with a refresh control for reloading data.

I've omitted the the UITableDataSource/Delegate methods as these are straight forward. The code below illustrates how I've designed the ViewModel and the ViewController to fit together.

**ViewModel.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) RACCommand *getItemsCommand;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *items;
```

**ViewModel.m**

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    @weakify(self);
    self.getItemsCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
        return [[ItemsDataSource getItems]
                doNext:^(NSArray *items) {
                    @strongify(self);
                    // I actually do a little extra work here such as sorting
                    // the items appropriately for the view.
                    self.items = items;
                }];
    }];

    return self;
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];

    RACSignal *refreshSignals = [RACSignal merge:@[
        [self.refreshControl rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged],
        [RACSignal return:nil]
    ]];

    [refreshSignals
     subscribeNext:^(id x) {
         [self.viewModel.getItemsCommand execute:nil];
     }];

    [RACObserve(self.viewModel, items)
     subscribeNext:^(NSArray *items) {
         [self.tableView reloadData];
     } completed:^{
         [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
     }];
}
```

**Questions/Problems**

1. The `completed` block where I call `endRefreshing` never gets executed and for the life of me I can't figure out why.
2. Would it be better to use a public method `- (RACSignal *)getItems` instead of the `getItems` RACCommand?
3. Is my usage of `doNext:` in the ViewModel correct in order to apply side effects (i.e. the sorting of the items array) without causing an additional subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Well, let's look at the signal:

```
RACObserve(self.viewModel, items)
```

When will that complete? Only when `self.viewModel` or `self` is deallocated, just like any other `RACObserve`. As long as those objects are around, it'll keep on `next`ing any time you set `self.items`.

It appears that you want it to `endRefreshing` once the `getItemsCommand` finishes executing, and you have this sort of implicit expectation that, since you know that command sets `self.viewModel.items`, that completion will somehow propagate -- but this isn't the case. To see when the command completes, you have to subscribe to the command's returned signal.

2) The advantage of `RACCommand` is the auto enabling/disabling behavior, which you aren't really taking advantage of here. The more canonical thing to do would be `self.refreshControl.rac_command = self.viewModel.getItemsCommand;`. That'll handle the `endRefreshing` stuff for you, saving you the headache from part 1.

3) ...sort of. The `do*` family of methods injects side effects for *every subscription to the signal*. So if you subscribe to a signal twice, and it sends a next, any `doNext` block it has will be invoked twice. An explicit subscription is more clear, since you want to execute this exactly once per next, regardless of how many times it's subscribed to.

```
    @weakify(self);
    self.getItemsCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
        RACSignal *itemsSignal = [ItemsDataSource getItems];
        [itemsSignal subscribeNext:^(NSArray *items) {
            @strongify(self);
            // Do stuff...
            self.items = items;
        }];
        return itemsSignal;
    }];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed and well written response. This clarifies several things for me. Using `self.refreshControl.rac_command = self.viewModel.getItemsCommand` is very nice however I do lose the ability to have the command executed on load. Calling `[self.viewModel.getItemsCommand execute:nil]` in `viewDidLoad` works but it feels as though I'm breaking out of the FRP paradigm. Is there a nicer way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know of a cleaner way to do it. `RACCommand` is in sort of a weird space between reactive and imperative already... there's no way to say "this should execute at this time" except via the `execute:` method. You can use lifting to make it...*look* more functional, but just goin' imperative occasionally is a way of life.

Comment: Ok not a problem, makes sense. After all we are working with an extension to an imperative language as opposed to using a purely functional language. Everything is working really well after incorporating your suggestions. Thanks again!

Comment: @IanHenry Performing subscription inside the signal block will cause two subscriptions to the signal, probably not what you want.

Comment: @tragicsans Calling `-execute:` explicitly is perfectly ok, that's why it's public. If it helps, you can think of `RACCommand` as kind of like a function, and `-execute:` is how you call/invoke the function.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest making `getItemsCommand` use `-map:` to sort and process the items array. Leave any other side effect work to be done in a separate `-doNext:`. Once you have your command following this pattern (which is more compositional in RAC), then you can use the `RAC()` macro to assign the command's finished product, the sorted array, to the `items` property.

```
RAC(self, items) = [self.getItemsCommand.executionSignals concat];
```

RAC has a built-in command support for `UIRefreshControl` that will start/stop the refresh control along with the start/stop of the command. You should find that you can reduce your `UIRefreshControl` code to:

```
self.refreshControl.rac_command = self.getItemsCommand;
```

For table reloading, you can do:

```
[RACObserve(self, items) subscribeNext:^(id _) {
    @strongify(self);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that makes perfect sense. I've successfully removed all side effects from the signal block of the command. Working like a charm.